# Adding multiple facebook like button

Tags: php

I want to open facebook like button through ajax fancy box.When I use iframe all images having like button when i click any one like button all images are become like.
When I try to use  then first time facebook like button show but after that it is not showing.

I use code for iframe

> .html&image=&layout=standard&show_faces=true&width=450&action=like&font=arial&colorscheme=light&send=true"
>   scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"
>   style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:px">

and for fb like

> window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
>           FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});         };      (function() {           var e =
>   document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;             e.src =
>   document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
>             document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);      }());
>         (function(d, s, id) {
>           var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
>           if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
>           js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
>           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
>           fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);         }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
>                 " 
>   layout="button_count" show_faces="false">

Please help me ................

Answer (score 1):

I get the solution now it is working but error message show when i like on like button the iframe code is

```
 <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode('http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])?>" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:50px"></iframe>
```